# convergence of a sequence satisfying functional inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck with this "funny" problem.
Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequel of real numbers such that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*, \quad \exists C_k \in \mathbb{R}^+, \quad 
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \quad \left| u_n - u_{kn} \right| \le \dfrac{C_k}{n^p}.
$$
Here, $p$ is any integer you want (take $p = 2015$ if it helps).
Is the sequence $u_n$ converging? Or do you have a counter example?

Thank you very much for your answers.

D

Comment: Perhaps you want $L = n$?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much and sorry for that, It is now correct.